# Malformed CSV at end

Tags: vb.net, parsing, csv, streamreader, datareader

Hey all i am trying to figure out a way of correcting the error in my CSV file before it errors out with a **MalformedLineException**.

My code is this:

```
Using myreader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\temp.csv")
        myreader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        myreader.Delimiters = New String() {",", "\n"}
        myreader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True 'Added

        While Not myreader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentrow = myreader.ReadFields()
```

The error is on the **currentrow = myreader.ReadFields()**. It's caused by not having the end quote in the last line of the CSV:

```
"xx.xxx.xxx.xx","2012-05-15 13:15:54","Bob Barker","bbarker@priceisright.com","
```

It should read:

```
"xx.xxx.xxx.xx","2012-05-15 13:15:54","Bob Barker","bbarker@priceisright.com",""
```

How can i correct this **before** it gets to the line **currentrow = myreader.ReadFields()**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to add the quote:

```
File.AppendAllText(filePath, """")
```

Comment: You would need to do that before you opened `myreader`.  The problem is that you've attempted to open a csv file that's not legal csv.  This corrects the problem before you open it.